# Load a single frame from a TIFF into R with EBImage or similar

Tags: r, image-processing, tiff

I am analysing a TIFF file in R. The TIFF only has one colour/channel, however it is from a movie that has ~1000 frames and so is very large. I have tried using the following command with EBImage to load the image data as a Matrix into R:

```
img <- readImage(file, as.is = TRUE)
```

However the computer's RAM is totally overloaded by the huge file, and I get the following error message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 22.4 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readTIFF(x, all = all, ...) :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 50838 (0xc696) encountered
2: In readTIFF(x, all = all, ...) :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 50839 (0xc697) encountered
3: In array(unlist(arg.list, use.names = FALSE), dim = c(arg.dim[-along,  :
  Reached total allocation of 65170Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In array(unlist(arg.list, use.names = FALSE), dim = c(arg.dim[-along,  :
  Reached total allocation of 65170Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In array(unlist(arg.list, use.names = FALSE), dim = c(arg.dim[-along,  :
  Reached total allocation of 65170Mb: see help(memory.size)
6: In array(unlist(arg.list, use.names = FALSE), dim = c(arg.dim[-along,  :
  Reached total allocation of 65170Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

My proposed solution is to create a loop that will open each frame individually, perform and store my analysis, then move onto the next image. The TIFF package called by EBImage offers an option to open only the first frame (`all = FALSE`), but not to open a frame of one's choice. Is there a way I can open each frame individually?

Comment: To the down-voter, do you have any criticism or suggestion for improving the question that you could share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[RBioFormats](https://github.com/aoles/RBioFormats)** provides a solution to read only selected frames from a larger image stack. It interfaces the BioFormats Java library rather than the R package tiff.

To install the package from GitHub, run

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("aoles/RBioFormats")
```

You can then use the `subset` argument to `read.image()` to specify the frames to read. The resulting object is of class *AnnotatedImage*, which is a subclass if the EBImage *Image* class. See the [package vignette](https://rawgit.com/aoles/RBioFormats/master/vignettes/RBioFormats.html) for details, and the following example for an illustration of the subsetting approach.

```
library(EBImage)
library(RBioFormats)

f <- system.file("images", "nuclei.tif", package="EBImage")

metadata <- read.metadata(f)

frames <- metadata$coreMetadata$sizeT

for(i in 1:frames) {
  frame <- read.image(f, subset=list(T=i))
  frame <- resize(frame, 128)
  display(frame)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this quite often.  If you break the 1000 frame movie into 1000 tiff files using ffmpeg:

```
 ffmpeg -i $name_of_movie ./directory_of_tiff_frames/%04d.tiff
```

you can easily read each tiff file into R with a loop like you said.  I suggest using the TIFF package, which you already have installed, with something like:

```
library(tiff)

## cd to the directory with the tiff files
setwd('./directory_of_tiff_frames')

## read in a character string of all the names of the frames
frames = list.files(pattern=*.tiff) ## in case there are non tiff files

i=1
while(i<=length(frames)) {
    ## read in the current frame
    cur.frame = readTIFF(frame[i])
    ## now you can perform any number of operations

    ## save your altered matrix as a .tiff 
    tiff('name_your_tiff_file')

    i=i+1
}
```